# What are my options for accessing the user's GPS device in a desktop browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, geolocation, gps

After reading about [Firefox's Geolocation](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/geolocation/) functionality, which [doesn't use GPS](https://superuser.com/questions/16457/list-of-gpss-compatible-with-firefox-3-5), I'm wondering what it would take for a browser (IE and/or Firefox) to be able to access a GPS device connected to a normal laptop/desktop computer?

So far the only technology I've found that seems to be able to do this is [Google Gears' Geolocation API](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_geolocation.html) or device specific APIs such as this [Garmin plugin](http://www8.garmin.com/products/communicator/).

Are there any other/better solutions? Browser plugins/extensions are fine for this purpose.

**Update**: I don't mind elevating the security privileges of the browser, using a plugin etc.

**Update**: "Firefox 3.6 (Gecko 1.9.2) added support for using the GPSD (GPS daemon) service for geolocation on Linux": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_geolocation

Comment: javascript downloaded from a remote server won't be able to interact with it for security reasons anyway

Comment: German magazine c't has a project that combines a GPS mouse and some Java for a browser-based tracking system (i.e. Laptop+GPS+Java app write location data to a PHP server that can be accessed from there using a browser). But that's not what you're looking for, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this [GPS in Browser](http://franson.com/gpstools/guide.asp?section=GpsToolsInternetExplorer&platform=net) tool will let IE actually get GPS coordinates via javascript from a connected GPS.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any browsers that support this right now, but the [W3C Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) is designed in such a way that a browser could use GPS to determine your location.  (Right now I believe the only browser that actually does use GPS is Mobile Safari on iPhone 3.0.)

In Windows 7, the [Location Platform](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/device/sensors/default.mspx) can use any number of location provider plug-ins, including those for GPS devices.  I don't believe IE8 officially has support for the W3C Geolocation API, but there are experimental versions that have supported it, so that may happen soon.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the only browser I was aware of that could natively get the client's GPS coordinates was iphone Safari.

Comment: Firefox 3.5+ supports the Geolocation API.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_geolocation

Comment: @Sean - thanks for confirming that, but it doesn't actually get the coordinates from a GPS does it

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to implement some web based software that runs on a mobile platform you could consider writing your own driver for the GPS that listens on port 80 and then use an AJAX applet client side to query the GPS driver for the current GPS co-ordinates.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any existing open source/commerical apps that do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, if you are using a serial port GPS then you simply have to open the serial port and send it a NMEA command and you should start receiving telemetry. If its over USB/Bluetooth its a bit more complicated but there are plenty of tutorials on how to do it. 

I suggest checking out GPSBabel, it looks promising: http://www.gpsbabel.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't answer your question, but [GPSd](http://gpsd.berlios.de/) is the most helpful GPS package I've encountered. Alas, it doesn't support any flavor of Windows.